# Cakephp: contain with limit 1 not showing any associated items where there are more than 1 of them

Tags: cakephp, limit, contain

I have 2 models:
Surveyaccess and Datapoint

They have HABTM relationship.

If I want to list each surveyaccess and associated Datapoints I can do this:

```
$t = $this->Surveyaccess->find('all', array(
    'contain' => array(
        'Datapoint'
    ),
    'conditions' => $conds,
));
//$conds are limiting me to a specific set of Surveyaccess items - not relevant here
```

BUT what I really want is to only show the first of each Datapoint items (if any)

I tried this:

```
$t = $this->Surveyaccess->find('all', array(
    'contain' => array(
        'Datapoint' => array(
            'limit' => 1
        )
    ),
    'conditions' => $conds,
));
```

I would expect LIMIT to limit the items returned to 1 - but instead it is simply returning an empty array when there are more than 1 Datapoint items like so:

```
(int) 0 => array(
        'Surveyaccess' => array(
            'id' => '63617',
            'browser' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.115 Safari/537.36',
            'created' => '2015-02-28 01:55:28',
            'read' => null
        ),
        'Datapoint' => array()
    ),
...
(int) 2 => array(
        'Surveyaccess' => array(
            'id' => '63615',
            'browser' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.115 Safari/537.36',
            'created' => '2015-02-28 01:42:58',
            'read' => null
        ),
        'Datapoint' => array(
            (int) 0 => array(
                'id' => '258',
                'DatapointSurveyaccess' => array(
                    'id' => '258',
                    'surveyaccess_id' => '63615',
                    'datapoint_id' => '258'
                )
            )
        )
    ),
```

Any thoughts on how to properly do this? I can process the array in PHP but that won't scale. I can also do a sub-query I guess...

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you need find('first')

```
$t = $this->Surveyaccess->find('first', array(
    'contain' => array(
        'Datapoint'
    ),
    'conditions' => $conds,
));
```

**UPDATED**

```
$t = $this->Surveyaccess->find('all', array(
    'limit' => 1,
    'contain' => array( 
        'Datapoint' 
    ) 
));
```

Comment: Nope. That just gets the first surveyaccess element with however many Datapoint elements belong to it. I am looking to get all surveyaccess elements, but only show the first Datapoint of each one. Thanks though..

Comment: Sorry. The updated answer doesn't work either - since the limit is now limiting the number of surveyaccesses being returned.   The goal is to return all surveyaccess - and for each one only return the first of however many Datapoints there may be.